# How to quit browser and restart my whole script after running first 200 users from excel?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have selenium java code working to read data from excel file and then use that data as username and then login in our website. However, my issue is we have 200k user name and after 300 username I get error that my session is expired. How can I close my browser after 200 user and restart my code from user 201 and then quit browser again at 400 and restart my code from 401 and so on. Below are my lines of code. Thank you.

```
 package loginAdmin;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class PersonateUserCopy
{
    WebDriver driver;
        
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws Exception 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
        "C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.example.com/Home.aspx");
        driver.findElement(By.id("M_layout_content_PCDZ_MW2NO7V_ctl00_webInputForm_txtLoginName"))
        .sendKeys("admin");   
        driver.findElement(By.id("M_layout_content_PCDZ_MW2NO7V_ctl00_webInputForm_txtPassword"))
        .sendKeys("Password");    
        driver.findElement(By.id("M_layout_content_PCDZ_MW2NO7V_ctl00_webInputForm_cmdContinue"))
        .click();       
        
    }
    
    @Test(dataProvider="testdata") 
    public void login(String username) throws InterruptedException
    {
        driver.findElement(By.id("M_layout_content_PCDZ_M5QH8YG_ctl00_lblUserName")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("M_layout_content_PCDZ_M5QH8YG_ctl00_txtUserName")).clear();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("M_layout_content_PCDZ_M5QH8YG_ctl00_txtUserName"))
        .sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.id("M_layout_content_PCDZ_M5QH8YG_ctl00_btnSearch")).click();
         
       driver.findElement(By.id("M_layout_content_PCDZ_M5QH8YG_ctl00_resultsGrid_ctl02_LogIn"))
       .click(); 
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().contains("Dashboard"),"User is not able to login"); 
        System.out.println("User is able to login successfully");
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[5]/ul/li[6]/a"))
       .click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("M_layout_content_PCDZ_M5QH8YG_ctl00_lblUserName")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("M_layout_content_PCDZ_M5QH8YG_ctl00_txtUserName")).clear();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        
    }
    
    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() throws Exception
    {
       driver.close();
    }
    
    @DataProvider(name="testdata")
    public Object[][] TestDataFeed()
    {
        ReadExcelFileCopy config = new ReadExcelFileCopy("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\testdata.xlsx");
        int rows = config.getRowCount(0);
        Object[][] credentials = new Object[rows][1];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            credentials[i][0] = config.getData(0, i, 0);
        }
            return credentials;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error log.

Comment: Hi, I don't get any error. My script is working fine. I just want to update it so that it quit browser every 200 iteration and continue with 201.

Comment: As a work around I am using @AfterMethod to quit my chrome session.

Comment: You can try to use an user index. When you reach 200, you restart the test and call again the provider method with the new starting index +1.